# Create a new "layout" in Dreamweaver for PHP Class

Tags: php, layout, dreamweaver

all;

I'd like to be able to create a new document in Dreamweaver that looks like this:

```
<?php
    class MyService extends BaseService {

    }
?>
```

So that I don't have to delete out the junk that DW puts in whenever you select one of the layouts that are in the new documents list and replace it with this bare-bones starter code.

What I have tried:

1) Saving it as a template.  This seems to be the old functionality where you have editable regions in an HTML page that get propogated automatically to pages created from that template...NOT what I need.

2) Following the instructions here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Using/WS64790c24e2ee40e79cb0f410a90931900-7ffba.html and putting it in my DW/configuration/BuiltIn/Layouts folder.  Unfortunately, this did not actually show up in the layouts list as suggested.

Is there an easy way to do this, or am I stuck just copying and pasting over the default HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dreamweaver looks for its default files in the following folder:

C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5\configuration\DocumentTypes\NewDocuments

What you could do is edit the Default.php file in that folder and replace the usual HTML stuff with your preferred code above.  That *should* work but I confess that I've never tried it.

Comment: Thanks!  Is there a place that this is documented where I could have found this?

Comment: Not really. Adobe's technet or forums may have a reference to it but I've been with Dreamweaver since version 3 so I just sort of knew about the default files from several years ago.  I can't remember if I read it somewhere or discovered it on my own.